# Is it possible to "Draw" a string to a canvas?

Tags: java, android, string, canvas, drawable

I've largely been using drawable resources to a canvas using a method similar to this:

```
image.setBounds(x, y, ( x + 100 ), ( y + 100));
image.draw(c);
```

I want to do the same thing with a string, or more specifically an integer. Point is, I need to be able to display dynamically changeable characters on the canvas. Is there an easy method to do this similar to the drawable method above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Canvas.drawText(...) method

Comment: I think he is using Java, not *javascript* :)

Comment: Correct. Java, Thank You! works, just gotta figure out the paint part, but the Canvas.drawText(String, int, int, Paint) method is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Graphics.drawString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29).